# Cambiar el orden de mis div al pasar a versión mobile

Tags: html, css, div, bootstrap-3

Quisiera cambiar el orden de mis `div` al momento de pasar a mi vista Mobile, los div en mi vista Desktop se ubica uno al lado del otro, pero al momento de pasarlos a Mobile se ve uno debajo del otro pero en este caso quiero que el `div` de abajo se ubique arriba, el código que construye los `div` lo tengo de la siguiente manera:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
  .row {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 15px;
  }
  
 .CeroPadCeroMar {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
} 
  .TituloRow {
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 0px;
  }
  
  .CeroPadCeroSust {
    padding-left: 10px !important;
    margin: 0px;
  }
  
  .Segmentos {
    padding: 15px;
    padding-top: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row" style="width:100%;margin-top:15px;">
  <div class="col-md-6 CeroPadCeroMar" style="min-height: 100px;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
    
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-md-6 TituloRow CeroPadCeroSust">
    <h2 class="Segmentos">
      "Titulo"
      <br>
    </h2> 
    <p class="Texto">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
    </p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

El div que quisiera ubicar arriba del otro es el que se llama `TituloRow`, quiero decir el que contiene el titulo, para controlar la manera en que se ve en Mobile utilizo `@media query`, estoy ayudandome con la versión de **Bootstrap 3.3.7**

**Actualización:**

Explicando un poco mas a detalle lo que estoy buscando hacer con los div agrego algunas imágenes de como se va actualmente en Desktop y Mobile.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y a lo que quiero llegar con solo la vista Mobile es lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si se fijan en los dos últimos div pase el que contiene el texto a la parte superior y el de la imagen abajo. En el código agregue solo los dos últimos div que son los que me interesa manipular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de ir y venir me di cuenta que no es posible cambiar el orden de mis div en vista de tipo Mobile, pero si es posible cambiarlo en vista Desktop.

Así que cambie el orden de mis div.

```
<div class="row" style="width:100%;margin-top:15px;">
<div class="col-md-6 TituloRow CeroPadCeroSust">
    <h2 class="Segmentos">
      "Titulo"
      <br>
    </h2> 
    <p class="Texto">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
    </p>
  </div>


  <div class="col-md-6 CeroPadCeroMar" style="min-height: 100px;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
    
  </div>
</div>
```

De forma predeterminada, se va a mostrar el contenido principal primero, por lo tanto, en la vista Mobile, el contenido principal se muestra primero.

Así que decidí usar `col-md-push` y col-md-pull podemos reordenar los div en Desktop. En conclusión el código me quedo de la siguiente manera.

```
<div class="row" style="width:100%;margin-top:15px;">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-6 TituloRow CeroPadCeroSust">
    <h2 class="Segmentos">
      "Titulo"
      <br>
    </h2> 
    <p class="Texto">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
    </p>
  </div>


  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-6 CeroPadCeroMar" style="min-height: 100px;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 

  </div>
</div>
```

Espero haber ayudado a alguien que se encuentre con el mismo problema.

Answer (score 0):

en lo personal lo hize facil y sin problemas con css grid, pero bootstrap igual tiene un sistema aunque algo mas raro por asi decirlo, se trata de "order", prueba esto en tu codigo, lo probe y me funciono

```css
.row {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 15px;
  }
  
 .CeroPadCeroMar {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
} 
  .TituloRow {
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 0px;
  }
  
  .CeroPadCeroSust {
    padding-left: 10px !important;
    margin: 0px;
  }
  
  .Segmentos {
    padding: 15px;
    padding-top: 0px;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <div class="row" style="width:100%;margin-top:15px;">
        <div class="col-md-6 order-1 order-sm-0 CeroPadCeroMar" style="min-height: 100px;">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
          
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-6 order-0 order-sm-1 TituloRow CeroPadCeroSust">
          <h2 class="Segmentos">
            "Titulo"
            <br>
          </h2> 
          <p class="Texto">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
          </p>
        </div>
        
      </div>
```

como te daras cuenta, unicamente agregue a tu codigo order-0 order-sm-1 al titulo y order-1 order sm-0 al otro div

```
<div class="col-md-6 order-0 order-sm-1 TituloRow CeroPadCeroSust">
<div class="col-md-6 order-1 order-sm-0 CeroPadCeroMar"
style="min-height: 100px;">
```

espero te sirva

Comment: Intente lo de tu respuesta pero no me funciono, estas seguro que puedo hacer uso de la propiedad `order` en la versión 3.3.7 de Bootstrap ?